# How to retrieve the schema.graphql file from @aws-cdk/aws-appsync before deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-appsync, aws-cdk

I am using the [code-first approach in @aws-cdk/aws-appsync](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-appsync-readme.html) for generating my graphql schema. For Typescript code generation purposes I need a way to retrieve the schema.graphql before deployment (maybe somehow extracting it from the `cdk synth` command?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For getting the automatically created schema before deployment, use this script:

```js
readFile('cdk.out/<YOUR-APP-NAME>.template.json', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
  const definition = JSON.parse(data)
    .Resources
    .<YOUR-SCHEMA-ID> // replace with your schema id
    .Properties
    .Definition;
  writeFile('lib/domain/generated.graphql', definition, (error) => {
    if (error) throw error;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if we are facing the same issue. Basically I wanted to access the GQL schema in my client react app which was in a different repository than the cdk app in which the infrastructure is defined.

I ended up using the aws-cli to extract the appsync schema using the following command:

```
aws appsync get-introspection-schema --api-id [API-ID] --format SDL --no-include-directives outfile=[OUTFILE]
```

Comment: Not the same issue tbh. For syncing the schema in my client app, I used amplify.